# why bridgewater filing only shows 10 billion in AUM

Tags: portfolio-management, finance

bridgewater supposed to manage 200 billion, but it 13F filling only shows 10 billion in AUM
https://fintel.io/i13f/bridgewater-associates-lp/2018-09-30-0

why is it?

Answer (score 5):

These are just single stock holdings in the US, excluding index derivatives positions/foreign positions. They are a allegdly a "macro fund" so I wouldn't expect them to do too much stock picking either. Actually most of their 13F positions are index ETF.